# Tab Control Events

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

Is there a predefined event for Tab Controls, or maybe something custom I can develop, that will allow me to execute some logic on a control I've removed from that Tab Control's Control Collection, before it ACTUALLY gets removed from the tab control.

Context :

I have a tab control with tab pages. These tab pages load documents related to entries in a reference grid. Each time I select a row in the reference grid, a tab page with the corresponding document loaded gets added to my tab control. The Check column for that row in the grid also gets checked.

I want to be able to close a tab page in my tab control and be able to relate this closed tab page to its corresponding entry in the reference grid so i can uncheck that row.

I've tried browsing through all the possible events for tab control and found nothing suitable. The ControlRemoved event fires only AFTER my tabpage has closed and tab focus has automatically shifted to the next tab.... This is causing my controlremoved logic to fail and enter an infinite loop, trying to close ALL the available tabs instead of just this one, and throwing an invalid index exceptions when it's closed the final one.

Comment: What UI library are you using? Winforms? WPF? ASP.NET? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that when you uncheck the item in your grid programmatically you do not update the tab control. Otherwise you always will run into an infinite loop causing the unwanted behavior.

You can achieve this by using a boolean flag. In the code-example below I haven't used the "real" event-handlers  because I have no IDE at hand to test this at the moment, but rather replaced them by simple methods, so get the idea:

```
private bool suppressTabUpdate = false;

private void HandleGridCheckedOrUncheckedEvent()
{
    if (suppressTabUpdate)
        return;
    // Insert logic here to create or remove the tab pages as required
}

private void HandleTabPageRemovedEvent()
{
    suppressTabUpdate = true;
    // Uncheck the item in the grid here
    suppressTabUpdate = false;
}
```

Comment: While I 100% agree that this will work, and I 100% admit that I've written code exactly like this many times, I find this code to be very difficult to maintain. For a simple app it's no big deal (just a bit hard to follow -- too much state!), once you have another widget, another behavior, or any other change to the form's behavior, you might regret it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's an exact event for you're looking for, but I have an alternative approach to propose.

It sounds to me that some of the UI code is too closely tied together. The grid and the tab control should not be talking to each other directly from the event handlers: that's what's causing the infinite loop (the events are "ping-ponging" back and forth).

Instead, I recommend that both the grid and the tab control be managed by another "component" (just a class, or a few methods in the existing form class) and that this component manage opening/closing tabs and modifying rows in the grid.

For example, when the user selects a row in the grid, don't modify the grid directly at all: instead, call a new method that does whatever needs to happen when a row is selected: check a checkbox, open a tab, etc. When a row no longer needs to be selected, don't change any selections directly: instead, call a new method that does whatever needs to happen when a row is not selected: uncheck a checkbox, close a tab, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a reference to your tab BEFORE it gets removed, there is one simple way to do it. Make CustomTabControl that inherits from TabControl and override its OnControlRemoved event.

If you have this:

```
public class CTabControl:TabControl
    {
        protected override void OnControlRemoved(ControlEventArgs e)
        {
            TabPage tp = e.Control as TabPage; // reference to tab page before it gets removed
            base.OnControlRemoved(e);// gets removed here
        }
    }
```